# Nonsensical close options

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

I was trying to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260902/wolfram-mathematica) as off-topic and I wrote a comment suggesting to post it on mathematica.stackexchange.com

But I could not do it because only three options were available, and apparently I had to choose between one of them to vote to close the question.

[image]

Now, either present all the sites (or give a way to specify one of them) or add the possibility to just vote to close without having to specify a particular site.

If there are deeper reason for the site behaving this way I apologize but I'd like to hear them! :-)

P.S. Apparently we have a mathematica tag which is supposed to be used for this type of questions, so I'm actually not sure if I should have voted to close or not. That's not the point however

Comment: There is an "other" close reason, which you can use for any reason that you can type into the box. Like some other close reasons, it is strangely located in the "off topic" section. But for this question, "off topic" seems to be accurate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll take this time to remind everyone of the golden rule of migrations:

## [Don't. Migrate. Crap.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446)

That question would not have survived on mathematica.SE, so there's no point trying to migrate it there. (Incidentally, [the question has been asked on mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81386), and doesn't appear to be doing so well right now.)

Onto the other issue. Adding a migration path to mathematica.SE was [requested, and declined](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3853), a while ago, and  [again not too long ago](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12960) (without a formal resolution). I'm not sure the situation has changed too much since then. There has been a [single question migrated there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205905) (with moderator help) in the last 90 days, and that migration was rejected.

And having the option for 3K users to migrate questions anywhere is *not* something I would get behind. The site moderators have this ability, plus a fairly convenient way to get into direct contact with moderators of other sites, and we *still* get it wrong (as evidenced above).

Comment: okay! But I wasn't suggesting to have the power to migrate questions directly.. in this case, if I thought that the question was off topic because I believed it belonged to another site, what should have I done? close with what motivation? As I said, I'm just trying to say that this feature as it is does not work. Either take it out completely or fix it! :-)

Comment: Our [help/on-topic] actually specifically mentions that questions about Mathematica are not on-topic. So closing as off-topic -> "This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center" would be fitting. If it is something that you feel really does belong on another site you can flag the question for moderator attention stating this. Though I won't say that we'll always agree with you.

Comment: okay thanks! One may wonder then why there is a mathematica tag, but I'll leave that for another question :-)

Comment: There is a Mathematica tag because there are existing Mathematica questions. (This site is older than Mathematica site.) Off-topic questions need tags too. Back to your first comment: the implication "question belongs on another site $\implies$ it's off-topic here" is false. You should evaluate whether a question is on-topic *here*, regardless of whatever other sites exist. If it's off-topic, *then* consider which of available off-topic reasons fits best.