# Why can't I select any other SE website when flagging a question?

Tags: discussion, flagging, migration

I flagged [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758452/matlab-script-to-plot-line-chart-with-two-y-axes-and-automatic-legend) recently. I wanted to select "this question belongs on another stack exchange network" but only three other SE sites came up (as shown below) when it asked which site it belonged on. Why can't I select stack overflow, or Mathematica stack exchange or something like that? Aren't these sites related to mathematics?

[image: allowed sites]

Comment: You can flag it as "not about mathematics".

Comment: Related older posts: [Flagging for migration to Mathematica.SE and Computational Science.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3853), [This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12960), etc. (You can surely find some other related discussions.)

Comment: In the words of Grace Note in those other questions, "Let's see how the statistics measure up right now."